# Including remote JS file via direct code injection with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying to directly insert a javascript script reference into a webpage via greasemonkey. For whatever reason, it doesnt seem to work. The code I have is as follows:

```
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = 'http://cubes-workbench.googlecode.com/files/test.js';
    headID.appendChild(newScript);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What does your JS console tell you? Any errors? `console.log(headID)`. Google "debug JS"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work unless (pick 1 or more):

- The document doesn't actually have a `<head>`.  Not all pages or iFrames do.
- The Greasemonkey script is set to run at document start.
- There is a browser add-on that blocks that JS -- *NoScript*, *AdBlock*, *RequestPolicy*, etc.
- A firewall or other security app or device blocks that script.
- The *include*, *exclude*, or *match* directives prevent the GM script from firing on the page or iFrame as you expect.
- Something else?

For starters, use a standard function.  Try this:

```
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() +
    ')()';

    var targ    = D.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
                || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node (null, 'http://cubes-workbench.googlecode.com/files/test.js');
```

If that doesn't work post your complete GM script and link to the target page.

Comment: thank you, I think it was a browser addon that was messing me up. 

Will including a script file in this manner allow the webpage to use it as if it had originally been coded in?

Comment: Yes it will. If you encounter complications, post a question, workarounds are usually possible.