# Using a Greasemonkey script to add javascript, from other sites, to a page

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Is it possible to use a Greasemonkey script to add in JS scripts from other sites to a page, so that they run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including remote JS file via direct code injection with greasemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597770/including-remote-js-file-via-direct-code-injection-with-greasemonkey)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply create a script element and add it to the document

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    var scriptElement = document.createElement( "script" );
    scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptElement.src = "url to your script";
    document.body.appendChild( scriptElement );
})();
```

If you simply want the script to run then this is enough.
If its a library like jQuery you want to use in your userscript it gets tricky.
There are 2 ways that I'm aware of:

- One is to use the [require](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require) tag of greasemonkey.
- The other one requires the same creation of a script element like shown above but you need to wait for it to load so `scriptElement.onload = function () {}` is needed and you'd have to use `unsafeWindow` to access variables from your library then.

I recommend the first method if this is a pure greasemonkey script because only than you script is encapsulated from the site.

Comment: +1 for `@require`. You don't need to wrap this code in an anonymous function.

Comment: Can I repeat using the variable `scriptElement` multiple times, to pull in multiple external javascripts? (such as script1.js and script2.js)

Comment: Also, is there a way to tell if this actually executes and adds this to the site(s)?  Since it pulls in a script for me which will pull in live information and data from a remote .js script, and its not, hence my asking.

Comment: @Lord Changing the src again means changing the value of the element in the document. I'd create multiple elements with multiple variables just to be safe.

Comment: That's what I figured, so i created three elements: `scriptElement1`, `scriptElement2` and `scriptElement3` and it all worked.  And I figured out why its not pulling in the data - DNS resolution was borked, since I forgot to update the local DNS server information xD

Comment: it doesnt work if i need load script from http for https

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this for example:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://example.com/somescript.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);  // execute the script
document.body.removeChild(script);
```

Comment: it doesnt work if i need load script from http for https

Comment: Will this always execute the script?  One doesn't need to wait for confirmation of execution before removing the child?